# Content Encoding Error when try to add an Article

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles

I have been doing some speed optimization tests and changes to improve a joomla 3 site and now the site and admin works fine until I try and add a new article and the page will not load I just get a browser "Content Encoding Error".
It seems to effect FireFox more than Chrome for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could happen when gzip compression is enabled and your browser isn't configured to accept compressed content.

Try the following

1. In Firefox address bar, type `about:config`
2. If a warning is shown, accept and proceed.
3. In search bar, type `encoding`
4. For `network.http.accept-encoding` option, double click on value
5. Change it to `gzip,deflate`. Click Ok.
6. Refresh and try adding a new article.

Comment: It worked again turning off gzip, thank you. But why cant I have gzip on the frontend and off in the back?

Comment: I am not too sure about if gzip is enabled for both (admin and frontend) or only frontend when you enable it from settings. Personally I too would prefer if it gets enabled only for frontend. But I believe that using htaccess you should be able to disable gzip for back end, e.g. administrator directory.

Answer (score 1):

1. Clear the browser cache
2. Clean Joomla Cache
3. If it still does not work then disable 'Gzip Page Compression' global configuration.

Comment: This is not a browser cache issue, but can see those 3 steps as worth a try to teach people before checking other things